# C# Update Location

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

My company is using an C#-ClickOnce application. Update location is a local storage path "192.x.x.x/Data/Software/xxx".

Current challenge:
I mapped a Storage-as-a-Service to "S:" on every client using the webdav standard. The folder "S:/Software/xxx" should be used as update location. The Visual Studio Publish Wizard doesn't accept any of the following strings:

//S:/Software/xxx/

file:///S:/Software/xxx/

\?\S:\Software\xxx    (UNC)

\.\S:\Software\xxx    (UNC)

The URL "https://webdav. .... /Software/xxx" works but the installation routine crashes because of the missing authentification.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of windows will the client computers run ? If they are running Windows 7+, you can use the Windows Vault for the storage of the credentials. Additionally, adding the update source as a trusted website on the internet settings should take care of your authentication problems. (this is not an answer to your problem but maybe another way to look at it)

Comment: I think Windows 10 is running on all clients (except the Server (Windows Server 2012)). Thank you.